# Error in running Spark in Intellij : "object apache is not a member of package org"

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-14

I am running a Spark program on Intellij and getting the below error :
"object apache is not a member of package org".

I have used these import statement in the code :

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext  
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._  
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
```

The above import statement is not running on sbt prompt too.
The corresponding lib appears to be missing but I am not sure how to copy the same and at which path.

Comment: what is the content of your build.sbt file ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure you have entries like this in SBT:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.0", 
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.1.0" 
)
```

Then make sure IntelliJ knows about these libraries by either enabling "auto-import" or doing it manually by clicking the refresh-looking button on the SBT panel.

Comment: I tried by adding the above librarydependencies too but still, it is not working :
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.spark #spark-core_2.12;2.1.0: not found

Comment: Change your Scala version to `2.11.8`

Comment: Thanks, it helped !

Comment: Glad to hear it. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the version-tip. I was constantly overlooking this part and trying with Scala 2.12.x version.

Comment: Did not resolve the issue , My SBT file is :
name := "HeadSpace1"

version := "0.1"

//scalaVersion := "2.11.11"

mainClass := Some("Main")

/*
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.3.1"*/

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.1.0"
)

Answer (score 2):

It is about 5 years since the previous answer, but I had the same issue and the answer mentioned here did not work. So, hopefully this answer works for those who find themselves in the same position I was in.

I was able to run my scala program from sbt shell, but it was not working in Intellij. This is what I did to fix the issue:

1. Imported the build.sbt file as a project.

> File -> Open -> select build.sbt -> choose the "project" option.

2. Install the sbt plugin and reload Intellij.

> File -> settings -> Plugins -> search and install sbt.

3. Run sbt.

> Click "View" -> Tool Windows -> sbt. Click on the refresh button in
> the SBT window.

Project should load successfully. Rebuild the project.

4. Select your file and click "Run". It should ideally work.